# Validate two models in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel-4, ardent

I have a form that represents two instances of a same `Address` class (let's say main address and billing address), which in turn inherits from `Ardent`.

The form is defined as:

```
Form::model($data, ...)
```

where:

```
$data = [ 'mainAddress' => [instance A of Address], 
          'billingAddress' => [instance B of Address] ];
```

The fields in the form have names that follow an array notation, such as:

```
Form::text('mainAddress[zipcode]')
...
Form::text('billingAddress[zipcode')
```

in order to pull out both models with ease with `Input::get('mainAddress')` and `Input::get('billingAddress')`.

I have some problems to find a concise way to check the validation errors for *both* the models.
Checking both the instances is no big deal, the problem is in the **view** where I must display the appropriate error next to the field; in normal cases I'd use a simple `$errors->has('fieldName')`, but with two instances I have problems in pulling out with ease the error message.

*Note:* I know that a solution would be to flatten the field names (f.ex. `mainAddress_zipcode`) and define a custom ruleset that comprises the fields of both the instances, but it seems likely that I'm missing a more concise and elegant way to do this.

Comment: would you please share your Model and view code?